# Cannot get FetchCotent_Populate to work for CLI11 getting message: No content details recorded for cli11

Tags: c++, cmake, fetchcontent

I am trying to use [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11) in a project via CMake.
However, I get thismessage: `No content details recorded for cli11` (extensive output below). I have add CLI11 in my CMakeLists.txt file according to 'Using Fetchcontent' section in [CLI11 Installation Chapter](https://cliutils.github.io/CLI11/book/chapters/installation.html).

```
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1221 (message):
  No content details recorded for cli11
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1740 (__FetchContent_getSavedDetails)
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.1/share/cmake/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:2033 (FetchContent_Populate)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (FetchContent_MakeAvailable)
```

The bare minimum to reproduce the issue.
First the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(app VERSION 0.0.0 DESCRIPTION "app" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -O3")

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Populate(
    cli11_proj
    QUIET
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11.git
    GIT_TAG v2.3.2
    SOURCE_DIR     cli11_proj
  )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cli11)  




add_subdirectory(${cli11_proj_SOURCE_DIR} ${cli11_proj_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

add_executable(app ../src/app/app.cpp)
target_include_directories(app PRIVATE include CLI11::CLI11)
```

Then the `app.cpp` file located in a folder `./src/app`

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <CLI/CLI.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CLI::App app{"App description"};
    argv = app.ensure_utf8(argv);

    std::string filename = "default";
    app.add_option("-f,--file", filename, "A help string");

    CLI11_PARSE(app, argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The documentation of CLI11 is wrong. It should be `FetchContent_Declare` instead of `FetchContent_Populate`, and the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` call needs to use the same identifier that was used with `FetchContent_Declare`, i.e. it should be `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cli11_proj)`. The `add_subdirectory` call is also superfluous (and might cause issues), as this is already handled by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`.

Comment: Also, `FetchContent_Declare` and following `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` should be called with the same first parameter. (In the referenced documentation these parameters differ: `cli11_proj` and `cli11`).

Comment: Well this got me further now I just get a bunch of errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some other problems with your code, in addition to Corristo's answer. Here's a sum-up:

1. Use `FetchContent_Declare` and `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` instead of `FetchContent_Populate`.
2. The first argument for both functions is `<name>` and must be identical.
3. Do not use `add_subdirectory`, this is done automatically by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` after the repository has been cloned.
4. You may ommit `SOURCE_DIR`, there is no need for it. Let CMake handle the directory layout.
5. Do not use `target_include_directories`. You want to link against `CLI11::CLI11`, so you have to use `target_link_libraries`. The include path is added automatically to your target.
6. The function `ensure_utf8` is only available in `main` (according to [GitHub](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11#adding-options)). You may change `GIT_TAG` to `main` or stop using it.

This is how the final CMakeLists.txt should look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(app VERSION 0.0.0 DESCRIPTION "app" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -O3")

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    cli11
    QUIET
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11.git
    GIT_TAG v2.3.2
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cli11)  

add_executable(app ../src/app/app.cpp)
target_include_directories(app PRIVATE include)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE CLI11::CLI11)
```